# Which arxiv-category should computability theory be submitted to?

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, arxiv

There are two categories on the arXiv that seem like a potential fit for computability research to me, although none of them explicitly lists it in the description. These would be:

cs.LO

> Covers all aspects of logic in computer science, including finite model theory, logics of programs, modal logic, and program verification. Programming language semantics should have Programming Languages as the primary subject area. Roughly includes material in ACM Subject Classes D.2.4, F.3.1, F.4.0, F.4.1, and F.4.2; some material in F.4.3 (formal languages) may also be appropriate here, although Computational Complexity is typically the more appropriate subject area.

math.LO

> Logic, set theory, point-set topology, formal mathematics

In the past, I've felt that it doesn't matter - they are crosslisted anyway, and whether computability theory belongs to computer science or mathematics is a pointless question (the answer is "both"). I've usually picked cs.LO to have included on dblp.

When submitting something to the arXiv today, an automated classification system raised the suspicion that cs.LO might be the wrong category, and that I should submit to math.LO instead. I'm now wondering whether there is a consensus on this, or additional information from the arXiv-team on such decisions.

Comment: Have you looked at other papers which are close to your topic, and seeing which category they are in?

Comment: One possible guide: is the paper more naturally classified using the AMS Mathematics Classification System or the ACM Computing Classification System?

Comment: I would use both, but there's a caveat: One of the orderings (cs.LO main and math.LO cross, or viceversa---can't remember which) is announced on the *main* mailing but it is **not announced** in the *cross* mailing!